# Is $AA^T$ invertible when $A$ is a $3\times 4$ matrix of rank $2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let 
$$
A =\left( 
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & -1 & 2 & -4 \\
2 & 1 & 4 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
Is $AA^T$ invertible? Justify your answer.

I know that the rank of the matrix is 2 and maybe that has something to do with the answer. But I'm not sure.

Comment: What can you say about the rank of $AA^T$ then? And what's its size (in the matlab sense)?

Comment: I know that the rank of A is 2. I'm unsure about the rank of $AA^T$.

Comment: I would say the rank is 3

Comment: I made changes to the matrix. It's 2 now. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank(XY)\leq\min\{\rank(X),\rank(Y)\}
$$
whenever the matrix product $XY$ is defined. In our example we have
$$
\rank(AA^\top)\leq\min\{\rank(A),\rank(A^\top)\}=\rank(A)=2<3
$$
What can we conclude?

Comment: Since the rank is 2, inverse does not exist. (4X4 matrix) Correct ?

Comment: Note that $AA^\top$ is $3\times 3$ but yes this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The rank of a product of matrices is no greater than the least rank of those matrices.

Comment: Indeed, a proof of this could be based on the geometrically intuitive fact that the dimension of a linear space can only drop or (at best) stay the same, but never rise, under a linear transformation. I.e., $$\dim A\mathcal V\leq\dim\mathcal V\text{ for linear spaces }\mathcal{V,W}\text{ and linear map }A:\mathcal V\to\mathcal W.$$